# RegEx: Extract formatted number from string if it exists

Tags: regex

First off, I'm sorry if this has already been asked somewhere else, it's just I could not find it. If it has been, I apologize deeply.

I am terrible at Regular Expressions and generally avoid them but I know the problem I have can be simply solved using them so I have come here for help.

I have a text field containing some information about a company (name, address, identifier, etc), but not all information always appears on the field and the order the information appears in is not set.

What I need is the company identifier which is a 14-digit number which can or cannot be formatted as such: XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX

What expression could I use that would identify if there are either 14 digits in a row or the number formatted in the manner described above?

Comment: Please provide some detail about what you have already tried and what is not working. You should not simply ask for someone to solve your problem for you.

Comment: What should I have tried? The only other solution I could think of would be to do some rather complex and slow string manipulation on the text field and that's not really an option. I know for a fact RegEx can solve my problem but don't have the knowledge to write the expression itself and couldn't find the solution to this exact problem. What is Stackoverflow for if not for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{3}[.]{1}[0-9]{3}[\/]{1}[0-9]{4}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}/` for `XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX`

`/[0-9]{14}/` for 14 digits

There's probably some edge cases in here somewhere.

There's also probably a way to do both of these in one, but I don't have the patience nor the time to try and figure it out.

Comment: `[0-9]` could be `\d`, `[.]{1}` could be `\.`, etc

Comment: @alex yeah absolutely

Comment: Nice one alex. With both your answers I could write a regex which did exactly what I needed it to do. You're awesome.

Comment: Final expression I ended up using:   (\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2})|(\d{14})

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `\b(?:\d{14}|\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2})\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XpQ8c4/1)